# [error]The operation was canceled on Azure DevOps Server pipeline Build

Tags: azure, azure-devops, tfs, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

We are using the Azure DevOps server 2019 and we created agent pool and configure two agents in single server. Now my problem is when am trying to run the two pipelines on this pool parallel, anyone of them cancelling after few minutes with error: The operation was cancelled without any logs. I don't know why it is happening. Single job is running successfully but on parallel jobs, anyone pipeline failing with above error. Is this cause because of running two agents in single server, building on single msbuild. Please someone help me on this. Attaching few pipeline screenshots. Thank you.[image]

[image]

[image]

**Please find the below system.debug logs of two different pipelines failed with same error:**

```
##[debug]Re-evaluate condition on job cancellation for step: 'Build solution **/*.sln'.
##[debug]Leaving Get-SolutionFiles.
##[debug]Leaving C:\agents\w1\_tasks\MSBuild_c6c4c611-aa2e-4a33-b606-5eaba2196824\1.166.2\MSBuild.ps1.
##[error]The operation was canceled.
##[debug]System.OperationCanceledException: The operation was canceled. at System.Threading.CancellationToken.ThrowOperationCanceledException() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Util.ProcessInvoker.ExecuteAsync(String workingDirectory, String fileName, String arguments, IDictionary`2 environment, Boolean requireExitCodeZero, Encoding outputEncoding, Boolean killProcessOnCancel, InputQueue`1 redirectStandardIn, Boolean inheritConsoleHandler, Boolean keepStandardInOpen, Boolean highPriorityProcess, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.ProcessInvokerWrapper.ExecuteAsync(String workingDirectory, String fileName, String arguments, IDictionary`2 environment, Boolean requireExitCodeZero, Encoding outputEncoding, Boolean killProcessOnCancel, InputQueue`1 redirectStandardIn, Boolean inheritConsoleHandler, Boolean keepStandardInOpen, Boolean highPriorityProcess, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.Handlers.DefaultStepHost.ExecuteAsync(String workingDirectory, String fileName, String arguments, IDictionary`2 environment, Boolean requireExitCodeZero, Encoding outputEncoding, Boolean killProcessOnCancel, Boolean inheritConsoleHandler, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.Handlers.PowerShell3Handler.RunAsync() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.TaskRunner.RunAsync() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.StepsRunner.RunStepAsync(IStep step, CancellationToken jobCancellationToken)
Finishing: Build solution **/*.sln
```

```
##[debug]  C:\agents\w1\106\s\ClientApp\node_modules\faker\lib\locales\de_CH\name (directory)
##[error]The operation was canceled.
##[debug]System.OperationCanceledException: The operation was canceled. at System.Threading.CancellationToken.ThrowOperationCanceledException() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Util.ProcessInvoker.ExecuteAsync(String workingDirectory, String fileName, String arguments, IDictionary`2 environment, Boolean requireExitCodeZero, Encoding outputEncoding, Boolean killProcessOnCancel, InputQueue`1 redirectStandardIn, Boolean inheritConsoleHandler, Boolean keepStandardInOpen, Boolean highPriorityProcess, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.ProcessInvokerWrapper.ExecuteAsync(String workingDirectory, String fileName, String arguments, IDictionary`2 environment, Boolean requireExitCodeZero, Encoding outputEncoding, Boolean killProcessOnCancel, InputQueue`1 redirectStandardIn, Boolean inheritConsoleHandler, Boolean keepStandardInOpen, Boolean highPriorityProcess, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.Handlers.DefaultStepHost.ExecuteAsync(String workingDirectory, String fileName, String arguments, IDictionary`2 environment, Boolean requireExitCodeZero, Encoding outputEncoding, Boolean killProcessOnCancel, Boolean inheritConsoleHandler, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.Handlers.NodeHandler.RunAsync() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.TaskRunner.RunAsync() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.StepsRunner.RunStepAsync(IStep step, CancellationToken jobCancellationToken)
Finishing: NuGet restore
```

Comment: Sounds like a resource contention issue to me. Does your server actually have enough available resources (i.e. CPU/memory) to run two parallel builds?

Comment: @DanielMann yes, it has enough resources to run multiple agents, but not understanding this kind of behavior

Comment: On the agent, check the worker logs themselves to see if they contain a hint in why job cancellation occurs. The agent has a `_logs` folder where it keeps this stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my investigation I found, When you download specific version pipeline agent from https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/releases, instead of Azure Devops portal and install, it has a mechanism to downgrade the agent to older version.
Use below steps to disable the downgrade.

1. Create a system environment variable **AZP_AGENT_DOWNGRADE_DISABLED**, set its value as **true**.
2. **Restart** the machine to make it takes effect.

For more info follow these links:
https://crushonme.github.io/2021/09/07/How-To-Disable-Agent-Downgrade-In-AzureDevOps/#how-to-disable-agent-downgrade

https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/issues/2589

Its working perfect for me.

[image]

Comment: You could Accept it as an Answer , it could help other community members who get the same issues to find the solution easily.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the simple error message , the cause of this issue maybe that the running time of the agent job has reached the maximum. please check the timeout in
For agent job: **Options -> Build job -> Build job timeout in minutes**

[image: set build job timeout]

If it doesn’t work, for further solving the issue, please define `System.Debug` and set it `true`. After setting it, you should see more detailed logs about the error :”The operation was cancelled “.

In addition, there is a note : Although multiple agents can be installed per machine, we strongly suggest to only install one agent per machine. Installing two or more agents may adversely affect performance and the result of your pipelines.
Please refer to doc :[azure pipeline agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#install).

You can use parallel jobs to run pipelines parallelly. Please refer to doc: [Configure and pay for parallel jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/licensing/concurrent-jobs?view=azure-devops&tabs=self-hosted#what-is-a-parallel-job)

Comment: If it helps, just a remind of accept an answer.  If not, i‘ll stay focused on your issue.

Comment: I tried with the build job time out increased, but there was no use, still facing the same issue. No logs available for this. It simply failing on the first job, when the other jobs queued. I tried with disable the one of the two agents, again its failed after few builds successful. Please help me.

Comment: please find the logs I just added above

Comment: this answer helped me, in my case it was the build job timeout which causes the operation cancellation